# Using word-wrap in Adaptive Cards ActionSet and markdown list

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards

I've been having issue with word-wrap property when using ActionSet with mark down list.

For some reason when I'm including a markdown list in the "ShowCard" the text get the wrap property but the binderies seems to be shifter to the right.

screenshot that demonstrate this issue:

[image]

When viewing in in dev mode (marking the component edge):

[image]

This works as expected without the bullets(list), but I need this design to work with bullets

The original card JSON:

```
{
    "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
    "content": {
        "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
        "type": "AdaptiveCard",
        "version": "1.2",
        "body": [
            {
                "type": "TextBlock",
                "size": "Large",
                "weight": "Bolder",
                "text": "Emergency Ambulance"
            },
            {
                "type": "TextBlock",
                "size": "Medium",
                "weight": "Bolder",
                "text": "Care Instructions:"
            },
            {
                "type": "ActionSet",
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "type": "Action.ShowCard",
                        "title": "Call an Ambulance",
                        "card": {
                            "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                            "body": [
                                {
                                    "type": "TextBlock",
                                    "text": "- The is a very long text, one two three four five six seven eight nine ten, eleven twelve thirteen fourteen .\n\n- The is a very long text, one two three four five six seven eight nine ten, eleven twelve thirteen fourteen .\n\n- The is a very long text, one two three four five six seven eight nine ten, eleven twelve thirteen fourteen .\n\n",
                                    "wrap": true
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This seems to work as expected in "https://adaptivecards.io/designer/" :

[image]

but in Bot Framework Emulator and other web client it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Try to use HTML Renderer to control your html markup manually - here is a link:
https://github.com/microsoft/AdaptiveCards/tree/main/source/dotnet/Samples/AdaptiveCards.Sample.Html

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't solve this issue.